# Translation tab under node/edit is missing for some nodes and visible for others, considering the fact that all nodes are same content type

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, transliteration

Problem: Translation tab under node/edit is missing for some nodes and visible for others, considering the fact that all nodes are same content type.

Example: I have a content type property and the "Enabled, with translation" option is also marked.

Let’s say I have 5 nodes type property"node1, node2, node3, node4 and node5". The translation tab for node1, node2 and node5 might be visible but missing for node3.

Core: Drupal 7

languages enabled: English, Russian and Romanian

List of enabled modules for translation:

Content translation

Translation overview

Language Icons

Localization update

Entity Translation

Block languages

Contact translation

Field translation

Internationalization

Menu translation

Multilingual content

String translation

Taxonomy translation

Translation sets

User mail translation

Variable translation

Views translation

Multilingual panels

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about the individual nodes? AFAIK, each node should have a language selected first before the translate button appears (cannot be language neutral)

Comment: @longboardnode every node is associated with an language.

I am not sure what is happening :/